# Can I rename fields in a numpy record array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to python so this may sound very basic. I have imported a csv file using csv2rec. The first row has headers. I want to change the headers to 'x', 'y', 'z'. What's the best way of doing this?

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
>>> r= mlab.csv2rec('HeightWeight.csv', delimiter= ',')
>>> names= r.dtype.names
>>> for i in names:
     print i


index
heightinches
weightpounds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mlab.csv2rec](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec) has a `names` parameter which you can use to set the column names:

```
r= mlab.csv2rec('HeightWeight.csv', delimiter= ',', 
                 names=['apple', 'pear'], 
                 skiprows=1)
```

When `names` is not `None`, `csv2rec` assumes there is no header row. So use `skiprows=1` to ignore the header row.

Answer (score 26):

You can simply assign to `.dtype.names`:

```
>>> d = np.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], dtype=[('a', float), ('b', int)])
>>> d
array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<i8')])
>>> d['a']
array([ 1.,  3.])
>>> d.dtype.names
('a', 'b')
>>> d.dtype.names = 'x', 'y'
>>> d
array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')])
>>> d['x']
array([ 1.,  3.])
```

Same way with `recarray`:

```
>>> d
rec.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<i8')])
>>> d.dtype.names = 'apple', 'pear'
>>> d
rec.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], 
      dtype=[('apple', '<f8'), ('pear', '<i8')])
```

Comment: If the array is a masked_array, then you will need to apply the same renaming operation to `d.mask.dtype.names`

Answer (score 3):

There is a `rename_fields` method in `numpy.lib.recfunctions` for that purpose. It also works with masked arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn

ab = np.ma.zeros(3, dtype=[('a', 'f4'), ('b', 'i4')])
xy = rfn.rename_fields(ab, {'a': 'x', 'b': 'y'})

print(ab.dtype, ab.mask.dtype)
print(xy.dtype, xy.mask.dtype)
```

Output:

```
[('a', '<f4'), ('b', '<i4')] [('a', '?'), ('b', '?')]
[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<i4')] [('x', '?'), ('y', '?')]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if any of the fields have `dtype=object`.