# Numpy genfrom text removes '.' from header names

Tags: python, numpy

When using genfromtext() numpy seems to remove the '.' character from the header name. Is there a way to turn this feature off?

#### file.csv header

> column1,column.2

#### cmd

```
a = np.genfromtxt(open('file.csv'), delimiter=',', names=True, dtype=None, autostrip=True)
```

#### results

```
> a['column.2']
field named column.2 not found
```

a['column2'] is however found.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16020137/1461210, http://stackoverflow.com/q/35234643/1461210

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to open a csv file with np.genfromtxt, I suggest you to use pandas.read_csv(namefile) instead; this would handle headers automatically.