# How do I add name columns to an existing numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dtype

I am trying to add column names to an existing numpy array.

I have seen in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429992/can-i-rename-fields-in-a-numpy-record-array) that `.dtype.names` provides (and sets) the column names of a numpy array.

However when I have an existing array and I try to name the columns I get the following message.

I am sure it is a basic question and I am missing something pretty basic, but still can not find the answer:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
a.dtype.names = 'ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-247-793bf2e18e51> in <module>
      1 a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
----> 2 a.dtype.names = ('ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC')

ValueError: there are no fields defined
```

EDIT:

It appears that only structured arrays can have named columns in numpy ([numpy, named columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037938/numpy-named-columns/20778800)) and that numpy arrays can not have named columns.

Comment: DSM's answer in the link shows how to create a `structured` array.  You can't 'add' column names to a existing array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your "plain" (unstructured) array to a **structured**
array, where each column has its name and type.

First import:

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn
```

Assume that your source array has been created as:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
```

Then to convert it to a structured array, run:

```
b = rfn.unstructured_to_structured(a,
    np.dtype([('Col_1', int), ('Col_2', int), ('Col_3', int)]))
```

(column names and types are arbitrary). If you want, you can pass different
types to each column, e.g. some columns can be of *float* type.

The result is:

```
array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)],
      dtype=[('Col_1', '<i4'), ('Col_2', '<i4'), ('Col_3', '<i4')])
```

If you want to refer to a column by name, run `b['Col_1']`
getting `array([1, 4])`.